# The revealed key of a contract in Michelson

Tags: contract, address, key

Checking signatures requires `key`s.  Currently, `key`s must be always given from the outside of Michelson.

Is there any reason why Michelson cannot obtain the already revealed keys of given contracts/addresses?

- Not allowed from some security reasons?
- Not required because we can use `SOURCE`/`SENDER` based authentication?
- Maybe useful but none has yet proposed it with convincing use cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we are in the third case:

> Maybe useful but none has yet proposed it with convincing use cases?

It is true that the keys must be given from the outside but so are the signatures so if one needs to combine signature checking and address-based authentication it is always possible to replace all occurrences of `signature` with `pair key signature` and use the [`HASH_KEY`](https://michelson.nomadic-labs.com/#instr-HASH_KEY) instruction (possibly followed by `IMPLICIT_ACCOUNT` and `ADDRESS`) to check that a given `key` and a given `address` match.

What we currently cannot simulate however is the ability to treat revealed accounts differently from not-yet-revealed ones and I don't see a use-case for this.

I don't see how having access the revealed keys could endanger the security. `SENDER` authentication solves many basic use cases but is not enough for some applications (multi-signature and fee-less transactions in particular) which rely on signature-based authentication instead. Finally note that another authentication feature named [Tickets](https://gitlab.com/cryptiumlabs/tezos/-/merge_requests/136) is being developed and might be proposed in a 007 protocol amendment.